# How to identify latest stable versions of Java(JDK) and Apache Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat

My applications are currently running in JDK 1.6 & Apache tomcat 6.0.33. I want them to be upgraded their respective stable versions. How can I find the latest stable versions for JDK & Apache tomcat?

Comment: off-topic for SO, Go the sites and read what the vendors say about the versions.

Comment: I don't see how this question is being upvoted. I'm ok with nobody *downvoting* it, it's just OT--but it hardly qualifies as a good question.

Comment: I think it is unanswerable in any forum.  What does "stable" mean?  Who decides if a particular version of Java or Tomcat is "stable"?

Comment: Every software comes with a beta version first, then it's respective stable(final or production ready) version will be released. As the vendor's website does not mention details about this(or may be i could not be able to locate). I don't think it is an unanswerable question in any forum.

Comment: *As the vendor's website does not mention details about this* this is just pain wrong! Who else could provide such information and how do you expect to get it in any other forum? *or may be i could not be able to locate* Yes, as for tomcat see here http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html (the first link in the download section) . Same goes for the jdk. In general if the vendor does not explicitly say it `apha` or `beta` or even `release-candidate` then it is a `release` or `final` version. Some vendors even always prepend such suffixes for their packages.

Comment: Of course such releases still can get updates for minor bug fixing or improvements, that's why you have some kind of minor version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest version of the JDK is the one listed for download on the [Java SE downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) page (JDK 8u25 at the time of this writing). The latest version of Apache Tomcat is always documented on the [Apache Tomcat Versions](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html) page (8.0.15 at the time of this writing).